# Ошибка MSSQL 2017 + python, unexpected indent во встроенной библиотеке

Tags: python, sql-server

При попытке запуска python-скрипта из SQL возникает ошибка, в которой говорится, что в каком-то файле из майкрософтовской библиотеки revoscalepy возникает ошибка типа IndentationError, вот код:

```
Сообщение 39004, уровень 16, состояние 19, строка 24
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Сообщение 39019, уровень 16, состояние 2, строка 24
An external script error occurred: 

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~1\MSSQL1~1.MSS\MSSQL\EXTENS~1\MSSQLSERVER01\D7564088-90B2-43EE-B88C-480460DB0F96\sqlindb.py", line 65
    if not isinstance(OutputDataSet, pandas.DataFrame):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 286, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params)
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
```

Пытался найти место в файле, где это происходит, но все дело идет во временной папке, которая очищается сразу после возникновения ошибки. Файл `sqlindb.py` не существует. Функции `px_call` и `rx_sql_satellite_call` скрыты в битовом файле (из revoscalepy), посмотреть который не представляется возможным.

Прикол в том, что раньше Python работал нормально, но недавно перестал, после того, как библиотека revoscalepy обновилась до версии 9.2.0. Раньше была 9.1.0.

Откат обновления не помогает, теперь не работает ни старая версия, ни текущая.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи, как можно добраться до битовых функций или какое-либо другое решение?

**Правка** Уточню, 
`if not isinstance(OutputDataSet, pandas.DataFrame)` - это кусок `revoscalepy`

Comment: А что за скрипт вы запускаете из SQL Server? `if not isinstance(OutputDataSet, pandas.DataFrame)` - это часть вашего скрипта или это "внутренности" `revoscalepy`?

Comment: да, в вопросе явно не хватает главного

Comment: В коде просто подключаю `pandas`. `if not isinstance(OutputDataSet, pandas.DataFrame)` - это часть `revoscalepy`

Comment: А "внутренняя" версия Python какая? Python 2 и Python 3 немного по-разному обрабатывают отступы, Python 3 более строго относится к отступам в коде.

Comment: Python 3.6 на SQL стоит.